# Searching registry for installed applications is branding interesting results

Tags: vb.net, registry

I use the following function to search through the registry in the following location: `"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall"`. It's missing a few entries though, like Symantec for example. If I manually open regedit to `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall` I can clearly see the subkey and it's Display Name.

```
Public Shared Function ReadRegistryFromRemoteMachine(machineName As String) As List(Of String)

    Dim programs As New List(Of String)()

    Dim softwareRegLoc As String = "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall"

    ' Open Remote Machine Registry Key 
    Dim remoteKey As RegistryKey = RegistryKey.OpenRemoteBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, machineName)
    Dim regKey As RegistryKey = remoteKey.OpenSubKey(softwareRegLoc)

    For Each subKeyName In regKey.GetSubKeyNames()

        ' Open Registry Sub Key
        Dim subKey As RegistryKey = regKey.OpenSubKey(subKeyName)

        ' Read Value from Registry Sub Key
        Dim softwareName As String = DirectCast(subKey.GetValue("DisplayName"), String)

        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(softwareName) Then
            If softwareName.ToLower.Contains("update") Then
            Else
                If programs.Contains(softwareName) Then
                Else
                    programs.Add(softwareName)
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next

    programs.Sort()

    Return programs

End Function
```

I've tried adding the 64bit reg node, still the same issue. Can anyone provide any insight as to why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add "\\" in softwareRegLoc while defining the subkey.

for e.g.

```
Dim softwareRegLoc As String = @"SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall"
```